# How do add icons to the li list items?

Tags: css

So i have a list of weapons and they have a star icon. I tried to change the list style but it didn't work out. These list items have a class of 'sui sui-star'
For example if i add this line of code it doesn't work,

```
<i class="fa fa-cloud">Machine Gun</i>
```

Is there any way to change the default list icons?I tried adding font-awesome classes to the li elements but none of it seems to work.

Comment: its probably because you have not imported the font-awesome

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using this Wordpress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ultimate/

It actually supports [FontAwesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons).
Simple change the class to `class='sui sui-[font awesome code]'`.

For example `class='sui sui-angle-right'` will be a chevron pointed to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Import the font-awesome:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud">Machine Gun</i>
```

If you still want to keep using SUI, you can do that as well. Just make sure you write the classes corretly.